# Python: modify a deque inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, deque

I know that it is possible to modify a list inside a function by using assignment as follows`lis[:] = new_list`, however **the question** is, is it possible to modify a **deque** inside a function as it is also an iterable?
Of course without using `return` inside the function.

It not possible to use 'deq[:] = new_deq ' as it gives the following error: `TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'`

Comment: Is there a question here? I believe it's yes, and verifiable in seconds within an interactive session. Just be sure to use the operations of the data type.

Comment: @BenY check my edits

Comment: Ah, that is clearer. Thanks, and looks like someone has answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deque` does not support a slice as an index, so to achieve the effect of `lis[:] = new_list` with a `deque`, you can clear it first before extending it:

```
from collections import deque

def f(q, new_list):
    q.clear()
    q.extend(new_list)

d = deque([1, 2])
f(d, [2, 3])
print(d)
```

This outputs:

```
deque([2, 3])
```

Comment: would that be efficient ? in terms of performance ? @blhsing

Comment: Yes it is as efficient as `lis[:] = new_list`, which costs *O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that it is possible to do it this way :

```
def f(q, new_list):
   q.__init__(new_list)
```

It is working for me, however I do not know if this way has any disadvantages.